# Modsecurity create config file with rules for specific URL

Tags: mod-security

I'm starting to learn about ModSecurity and rule creation so say I know a page in an web app is vulnerable to cross site scripting.

The rule in question would look something like this:

```
SecRule ARGS|REQUEST_HEADERS “@rx <script>” id:101,msg: ‘XSS Attack’,severity:ERROR,deny,status:404
```

Is it possible to create a config file for that particular page (or even wise to do so?) or better said is it possible to create rules for particular URL's?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do so. In mod-security they are having action called chain action like for example,

SecRule REQUEST_URI "/bank/login.aspx" phase:2,chain,t:none,id:105
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length "@eq 0" t:none

So you can change your rule accordingly. And google is your best companion for more info.